# NullReferenceException from Sitecore.Nexus on Sitecore 9.1

Tags: installation, fakedb

I am starting up my Sitecore 9.1 XP instance and I see the following error from `Sitecore.Nexus`:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.HasModule(String name) +146
   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_HasValidLicense() +21
   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.XdbSettings.get_Enabled() +8
   Sitecore.Xdb.Configuration.Pipelines.Initialize.ShowXdbInfo.Process(PipelineArgs args) +223
   (Object , Object ) +8
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +483
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists) +235
   Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain) +21
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Application_Start() +214
```

Also, my FakeDb tests are failing with the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Sitecore.Nexus.Licensing.NexusLicenseApi.GetSnapShot(Guid instance)
   at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager.GetSnapshotData(Guid instance)
   at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager.UpdateSnapshot()
   at Sitecore.SecurityModel.License.LicenseManager..cctor()
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Sitecore 9.1, this could indicate that your `license.xml` is missing from your data folder, which will typically be your `App_Data` folder. Place the license file in the correct location, and reset your application pool.

With FakeDb on Sitecore 9.1, this could also indicate that your `license.xml` is missing from the unit test root or the `LicensePath` is misconfigured in your `App.config`. Be sure you follow the [FakeDb Installation Documentation](https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Installation) to make your license file available.